# Edittext.Text shows right value but uses the wrong

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext, textview

i've searched in google and forum but didn't found anything about my strange problem. Sry for my bad english :)

It's really strange and difficult so i want to discribe it as simply as possible

1. User input in edittext (type: textPassword): 1 -> Logged in -> worked

   var loginResult = await connection.LoginAsync(this.Username.Text, this.Password.Text, WebLoginType.User);
2. Password encrypted it in "2FYM9iWHHecf45vPjjZPfg=="

   var newLogin = new LoginData
                   {
                       Username = this.Username.Text,
                       Password = Encrypter.Encrypt(this.Password.Text),
                       WebServiceAddress = this.WebServiceAddress.Text,
                       IsOnline = true,
                       IsActive = true,
                       License = this._license
                   };
3. Now on logout the password gets decrypted in "1" again, but in layout i can see it has more than one character in edittext. this.Edittext.Text = "1"

   this.Password.SetText(Encrypter.Decrypt(setting.LastLoginPassword), TextView.BufferType.Normal);
4. If i login again i can see this.Edittext.Text is "1" but WebService says that it is the wrong password

Now if i delete the characters in edittext and write manually "1" it works.
What magic is going on?

Comment: Show the relevant code....

Comment: trim value when you are fetching from edittext
string pass = trim(edittexName.getText());

Comment: *Added relevant code

Comment: @siddhesh that's already done by WebService. Edit: No it's not done and should not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved Probem: The Encrypter fills the rest of bytes with \u0000 until it gets its size of 16 bytes. I had to remove this with

```
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length).TrimEnd('\u0000');
```

Now it works.